# MacBook stays connected to wifi but loses internet connection

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, catalina, internet

Every few minutes my internet connection drops on my MacBook Pro 15" Mid-2015, running macOS Catalina 10.15.5.

It stays connected to wifi, at least it indicates as such in the menu bar and System Preferences.

However, I can't use the internet again until turning off and on wifi.

Also, I can't connect to my router's webpage itself (normally http://192.168.1.1/ is my router's config pages) when this issue happens.

However, from the terminal `ping` continues to work, for my router's IP and for names like `google.com`.

This issue breaks: Safari.app, Discord.app, `wget`, `curl`, `dig`, Firefox Developer Edition.app, Chrome.app, Folx.app, Mail.app, .... almost everything internet-related I can think of testing except `ping`. `ping` times don't even increase while the rest of the internet "drops".

This doesn't happen on any other device in the house.

How can I stay connected to the internet all the time without having to worry about needing to reconnect like this?

---

My MacBook, like all other devices the problem *doesn't*  happen on, gets its IP address using DHCP.

While the wifi is working:

[image]

While I can't connect to the internet:

[image]

> According to support.apple.com/kb/SP719, your Mac supports "802.11ac Wi‑Fi wireless networking; IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n compatible", is the wireless router configured accordingly?

I'm not sure how to check... but I found on one page of my router's settings "Generic MAC80211 802.11bgn (radio0)" this text.

Comment: How does your Mac get the IP address, over DHCP or is it static? According to https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719, your Mac supports "802.11ac Wi‑Fi wireless networking; IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n compatible", is the wireless router configured accordingly? When you lose your Internet connection, which are the RSSI and Noise values displayed for your wireless network when you Option-click the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar?

Comment: @jaume i added info to the question. `ping` continues to work for some reason

Comment: If you can ping Google, you didn’t lose Internet.  It appears to be an issue with browsing.  It might be s DNS issue as well.  Start with a different browser first and let’s go from there.

Comment: @Allan it breaks: Safari.app, Discord.app, `wget`, `curl`, `dig`, Firefox Developer Edition.app, Chrome.app, Folx.app, Mail.app, .... almost everytihng internet-related I can think of except `ping`. `ping` times don't even increase.

Comment: `ping` allows you to get out, but everything else fails?  What about `traceroute`?  Let's try something different.  Issue the command `traceroute -d bing.com` and let me know what you get.  (Google might be cached in DNS, so I figured Bing would force a DNS lookup)

Comment: Just to make sure, you're not seeing your firewall as the first hop?

Comment: Ahhh..Let me know when you get a result.

Comment: @Allan all hit 64 (max) hops, all timed out. The domain names were all resolved to IP addresses correctly, ping continues to work, even for things not in the cache (despite dig not working? weird...), but traceroute just `* * *` forever

Answer (score 1):

A recent article on Cult of Mac entitled [How to fix Wi-Fi and Bluetooth interference on a Mac](https://www.cultofmac.com/718687/fix-wi-fi-bluetooth-interference-mac/) may give some insight. In your screenshots, your wifi is running on 2.4GHz which is the same as Bluetooth according to the article.

> If a wireless connection is a must, you may find that a change in router settings is what you need. Wi-Fi and Bluetooth devices use the 2.4GHz band as standard, but modern routers also support the 5GHz band.

I was about to ask about my audio skipping that is playing over Bluetooth. I noticed that my router does have 2.4GHz running. I am currently testing to see if my problems are resolved.

Comment: Well, it doesn't happen on any other device in the house, and ping times don't increase, so I don't think it's due to interference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a couple of unsuccessful hours with Apple support I was ready to send my new MacBook back for a warranty repair.  The 'fix' in my case was easy:  I STOPPED USING FOLX!  I've not had this problem for 2 weeks now.  I now just need an alternative to Folx, compatible with Catalina (10.15.5)

Comment: This is very interesting. I actually have Folx installed, so maybe this is what causes it. I'll have to check next time I'm on that network.