# Macbook Wifi Issues

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

Think my issue may be related to this - [MacBook stays connected to wifi but loses internet connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396412/macbook-stays-connected-to-wifi-but-loses-internet-connection?newreg=47a0c012dc5748589609691a6f2756f3)

For the last 24 hours, my Macbook Pro (16in M1 2022) connects to WiFi but has no internet connectivity after a few seconds - it works for about 10-15 seconds and then stops. No errors etc.

I did install Folx yesterday, but have since removed it, but issue persists, but only with my main WiFi - I can connect to my iPhone and that works and doesn't disconnect.

I've done restarts, removed the WiFi network, tried with different networks, I've tried to reinstall but can't due to *drum roll* no internet. The network is working fine with another Mac in the house, with iPhone, PS5 etc so there is connectivity. The network is a 5ghz network.

WiFi Diagnostics shows

- Review WiFi Best Practices
- DNS Resolution Failure (I have tried different DNS, same issue, and that same DNS works on the other Mac)
- Custom DNS Settings review (again, did this, and didn't work)

Comment: Okay, I've wiped the mac totally via DFU restore, reset the router, and the issue still persists. It's essentially a brand new Mac now, with no Apple Id or backup restored. This is perplexing.

Comment: [this](https://www.howtoisolve.com/wifi-not-working-on-mac-after-update-os-x-yosemite-mavericks/) may give you some trick (the one with time/date seems strange, but who knows ?)

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried most of those (And yeah, the date time one seems weird, but that won't work anyway as can't connect to Internet to update :) )

It's totally perplexing - It works briefly if I reset, and it's survived a Macbook reset, and wipe, and a total factory reset on the modem - there's no blocked ports etc or anything like that. Next step is to disable the whole firewall and see if that does anything.

Comment: The last things is to go to an Apple Store so they can check if it is a problem with the Mac.

Comment: I only got it two weeks ago, so I'm not going to take anything but an exchange! No Apple Stores in my country anyway, so will have to deal with the store - I was onto my ISP and they could see nothing. Honestly, given that other Macs are working on the network, it's likely on my Mac

Comment: Just forgot to tell you that DNS failure is a consequence of internet connection failure as DNS is usually on internet .